# Redux hierarchical reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am wondering if I can nest reducers this way.

```
var combinedReducers  = {
        Tasks: TaskDuck.reducer,
        Approval:  {
                ApprovalDetail: ApprovalDuck.reducer ,
                ApprovalDecisions: DecisionsTasksDuck.reducer 
            } 
    };

    export const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers<AppState>(combinedReducers);
```

Comment: just give a try

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  You can call `combineReducers()` multiple times.  For your example, you'd want:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    Tasks : TaskDuck.reducer,
    Approval : combineReducers({
        ApprovalDetail : ApprovalDuck.reducer,
        ApprovalDecisison : DecisionsTaskDuck.reducer
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

combineReducers properties should be mapped to functions, not to objects. And as you can see here I added a function that returns the intended object and it worked.

```
var combinedReducers  = {
            Tasks: TaskDuck.reducer,
             Approval:()=> ({
                ApprovalDetail: ApprovalDuck.reducer,
                Decisions: DecisionsTasksDuck.reducer
            })
        };

        export const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers<AppState>(combinedReducers);
```